# Image Endpoints - Synxis - SabreDevStudio

Tags: python, image, sabre

Trying to optimize our room images, in the return from synxis we are getting a file location (c:\images\room.jpg) and then transforming that to a valid image URL. This is then redirecting to a storage.googleapis.com url.

Is this what other are doing? It seems very convoluted to all of these redirects.  We are only reading these images and never uploading the image files ourselves via our frontend app. All images are loaded via Synxis's management portal.

We were expecting a direct link to an optimized image from Synxis. Right now we are transforming the URL and letting things redirect to the image which is very slow.